Mexico is phasing out paper FMMs. How is the FMM rule enforced if entering by land and exiting by air?
I'm planning an itinerary where we would drive from San Diego to Tijuana airport (or possibly cross on foot), then fly to South America. It appears that paper FMMs are now being phased out and no longer issued at Mexican airports.
But... how is the FMM rule now enforced if leaving by air? Are you supposed to go show your paper FMM to someone at Tijuana airport? Earlier this year I've left Mexico via Puerto Vallarta airport and AFAIK nobody looked at my Mexican immigration stamp, nor were there any signs about FMM checks.

Not familiar with the way things are supposed to work in Mexico, but from what I gather (though there are lots of contradictory statements out there), while you need to have the paper FMM or the digital FMM or the stamp in the passport in case someone checks (upon leaving on even during your stay), there are no systematic checks.

First of all, you need to make sure to get your FMM. In most cases, when you enter Mexico by land from the US, you will only be waved through by the Mexican officer. You need to tell them that you want to get an FMM and stop by the immigration office. The FMM you get there will be stamped, and that stamp shows that you entered by land (the stamp includes a car shape). When you need to depart Mexico by air, you will need to stop at the immigration office of your departing airport where you will need to pay the tourist tax, which would have been included in your airplane ticket if you had arrived by air. Alternatively, you can issue and pay for your FMM online; however, you will still need to stop at the Mexican Immigration office at the border to have it stamped. If you do not show your stamped and paid FMM to the airline when departing, they will not issue you a boarding pass.

If you do not show your stamped and paid FMM to the airline when departing, they will not issue you a boarding pass => no longer true, I left from Puerto Vallarta this January without getting an FMM or showing it to the airline.
