EU (Schengen) citizen visit Mexico - Forms to enter/exit the country
I am a EU (Schengen) citizen planning to visit Mexico sometime next year. I will arrive by air from Europe to Mexico City (or some other major international airport in Mexico).  While researching entry requirements i've found different information regarding "Forma Migratoria Múltiple Digital (FMMd)" and "Customs form" that you should complete after arrival.
Some sources say that you have to apply for FMMd in advance online, some say there is a paper version, other say that the FMMd is no longer in use at certain airports.
The Mexican Embassy in Sweden says the following:

General requirements to enter Mexico.
Valid passport / Your passport should be valid at the time of entry
and during the period of your stay in Mexico. However, it is highly
recommended to contact the airline company you are traveling with, in
order to comply with their requirements. Temporary/emergency passports
are welcome in Mexico. Visa, if applicable. You need a visa? go to our
visa section∇ Remember that having a visa does not guarantee the
entrance to Mexico.
A custom form should be filled out online AFTER
your arrival using the information from the passport you used to enter
the country. Please go to the following link to obtain it  -
https://www.inm.gob.mx/spublic/portal/inmex.html
Recommended documents to be brought with you (printed):
Return ticket (airplane, bus, cruise e.t.c) Hotel booking details.
Insurance
At the point of entry, an Immigration Authority shall stamp your
passport allowing you to stay in Mexico for a certain amount of days.
If a number is not written, it means you are allow to stay up to 180
days.

The Mexican Embassy in Canada says this:

What documents do I need to enter Mexico?
To enter Mexico, you must have the following documents:   A valid
passport or travel document. There is no need for a minimum period of
validity of the passport (for example 6 months); but this document
must be valid during the length of your stay in Mexico.
A properly completed Multiple Digital Migration Form (FMMd). This form
will be provided to you by the airline or at the port of entry. You
can also complete this form online. Please click here:
https://www.gob.mx/inm/articulos/forma-migratoria-multiple-digital-fmmd?idiom=es
Please keep it in a safe place and do not lose it. You will be asked
for this document at your departure from Mexico.
Mexican immigration officers at the port of entry may request
additional documents depending on the purpose/activity of your trip.
Tourism: Hotel reservation, return tickets, etc.

Both links mentioned (https://www.gob.mx/inm/articulos/forma-migratoria-multiple-digital-fmmd?idiom=es and https://www.inm.gob.mx/spublic/portal/inmex.html) are only availible in spanish. The INM portal, (second link) only available in spanish, seems very difficult to navigate with options to 'create an account' and to 'search for something already created' (idk??)
Link about FMMd being phased out (from 2022): https://www.natvisa.com/mexico-blog/tourist-card-being-phased-out
How is the immigration and customs procedure when entering/exiting Mexico by air in 2024? Does the passport stamp replace the FMMd? Anyone recently traveled to Mexico from Europe and can shed some light on this?
Thank you in advance

Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/190032/mexico-is-phasing-out-paper-fmms-how-is-the-fmm-rule-enforced-if-entering-by-la
